# Django form not raising ValidationError for invalid email

Tags: python, django, validation, validationerror

So I have a form that looks like this and I know it works because leaving some fields blanks gives the correct error messages in the errors dictionary but email doesn't seem to be correctly validating

In **forms.py**

```
class NewUserForm(Form):
    username = UsernameField(required=True)
    password = CharField(required=True, widget=PasswordInput())
    email = EmailField(required=True)
```

And then in **views.py** I have

```
form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        # Do stuff
```

When I enter in an email such as *blah* it should fail for not having "@" (which should cause a ValidationError) to be thrown as stated in

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py
(line 105)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. In fact, even if I enter in no email it doesn't even state that the field is required

Comment: How are you displaying the form in your template? Add print or log statements to check what `request.POST` contains.

Answer (score 0):

The form object try/excepts the validation errors. If you want to display the form with its errors, you've to do:

```
form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
context = {}
if form.is_valid(): 
    # Do stuff
else:
    # "is_valid()" fills the errors and non_field_errors attributes of the form, you can render it now
    context['myform'] = form
    render_to_response('mytemplate.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

And in your templates, `{{ form }}`, `{{ form.as_p }}`, `{{ form.as_ul }}` will render the form with its errors in red.